# grpc BoolValue false value is equal to default one

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I have a field of type `BoolValue` in backend proto-file, and need to set it to true, false or empty on Android client.
However, i can set it only to true, the attempt to create a false `BoolValue` leads to just empty object.
Is it normal behaviour for grpc-java implementation, and can i changed it somehow?
Thanks

[image: proof from Android Studio debugger1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal behavior. There no way to know if the optional field was explicitly set or has default value.